# How to optimize PySpark when using multiple data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Looking to optimize the following code for speed. Extensive background in python and pandas, but new to pyspark. Any suggestions you may have will be greatly appreciated.

For clarity, the code has been broken up into parts 0 through 5. Feel free to address a single part or make a suggestion that efficiently ties all parts together.

**There must be a PySpark "trick" that circumvents the necessity of having to visit each column multiple times, right?**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct, col, isnan, when, count

df = spark.sql("""SELECT {}
                  FROM db.tbl
                  WHERE tbl.year = '2019'""".format(sql_string))
print(df.count(), len(df.columns))


# 0. Find Number of Distinct Values for each Column
distinct_value_dict = {}
for i, x in enumerate(df.columns):
    df0 = df.agg(countDistinct(x).alias('c')).collect()
    distinct_value_dict[x] = int(str(df0)[7:-2])
    print(i, ',', end="")
df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(distinct_value_dict, orient='index', columns=['Distinct Values'])
df0.to_csv('db_2019_0.csv')
print('df0: Distinct Values... COMPLETE!')


# 1. Find Data Type of each Column
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes).rename(columns={0:'Column Name', 1:'Data Type'}).set_index('Column Name')
df1.to_csv('db_2019_1.csv')
print('df1: Data Type... COMPLETE!')


# 2. Count the 'Missing Values' for each Column: Count None, Null, empty, Nan with string literals.
df2 = df.select([count(when( col(c).contains('None') | \
                             col(c).contains('NULL') | \
                             (col(c) == '' ) | \
                             col(c).isNull() | \
                             isnan(c), c )).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
                    ).toPandas().transpose().rename(columns={0:'Missing Values'})
df2.to_csv('db_2019_2.csv')
print('df2: Missing Values... COMPLETE!')

 
# 3. Generate Descriptive Statistics: Row Count, Mean, Std Dev, Min, Max
df3 = df.describe().toPandas().set_index('summary').transpose().rename(columns={'summary':'Column Name', 'count':'Row Count', 'mean':'Mean', 'stddev':'Std Dev', 'min':'Min', 'max':'Max'})
df3.to_csv('db_2019_3.csv')
print('df3: Describe... COMPLETE!')


# 4. Determine the Mode for each Column
df4 = pd.DataFrame([[i, df_tops.groupby(i).count().orderBy('count', ascending=False).first()[0]]
                    for i in df.columns]).rename(columns={0:'Column Name', 1:'Mode'}).set_index('Column Name')
df4.to_csv('db_2019_4.csv')
print('df4: Mode... COMPLETE!') 


# 5. Concat descriptive values for each of the columns
df_summary = pd.concat([df1, df0, df2, df3, df4], axis=1).sort_values(by='Missing Values')
df_summary
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension did not improve performance for #0. I found it to be more efficient to extract the distinct value count from the string and add it to a dictionary.

```
# 0. Find Number of Distinct Values for each Column
distinct_value_dict = {}
for i, x in enumerate(df.columns):
    df0 = df.agg(countDistinct(x).alias('c')).collect()
    distinct_value_dict[x] = int(str(df0)[7:-2])
    print(i, ',', end="")
df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(distinct_value_dict, orient='index', columns=['Distinct Values'])
df0.to_csv('db_2019_0.csv')
print('df0: Distinct Values... COMPLETE!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to determine if creating a pandas data frame using pd.DataFrame() vs .toPandas() was consistently faster. Similarly, rename as a pyspark df or pandas df, had negligible improvements in speed.

```
# 1. Find Data Type of each Column
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes).rename(columns={0:'Column Name', 1:'Data Type'}).set_index('Column Name')
df1.to_csv('db_2019_1.csv')
print('df1: Data Type... COMPLETE!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these have little room for improving.

```
# 2. Count the 'Missing Values' for each Column: Count None, Null, empty, Nan with string literals.
df2 = df.select([count(when( col(c).contains('None') | \
                             col(c).contains('NULL') | \
                             (col(c) == '' ) | \
                             col(c).isNull() | \
                             isnan(c), c )).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
                    ).toPandas().transpose().rename(columns={0:'Missing Values'})
df2.to_csv('db_2019_2.csv')
print('df2: Missing Values... COMPLETE!')

 
# 3. Generate Descriptive Statistics: Row Count, Mean, Std Dev, Min, Max
df3 = df.describe().toPandas().set_index('summary').transpose().rename(columns={'summary':'Column Name', 'count':'Row Count', 'mean':'Mean', 'stddev':'Std Dev', 'min':'Min', 'max':'Max'})
df3.to_csv('db_2019_3.csv')
print('df3: Describe... COMPLETE!')
```

With that said, one could use the fact that all columns in db are strings to simplify the columnwise search:

```
# 2. Count the 'Missing Values' for each Column: Count None, Null, empty, Nan with string literals.
df2 = df.select([count(when( (col(c) == '' ), c )).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).toPandas().transpose().rename(columns={0:'Missing Values'})
df2.to_csv('db_2019_2.csv')
print('df2: Missing Values... COMPLETE!')
```